# Sharepoint webpart installation on a farm

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

I was wondering about how the order of installing things affects the system:

Scenario 1:

- I have a sharepoint farm with a single server
- I install a webpart on the farm
- I then add a new server to the farm
- Will the webpart be available on the second server?
- If not what do I have to do to make it work?

Scenario 2:

- I have a Sharepoint farm with 2 servers
- I install a webpart by running a setup project on one of the servers
- Will the webpart be available on the second server?
- If not what do I have to do to make it work?

Thanks

Shiraz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how the web part is delivered.

If it's nicely packaged into a wsp solution package. Then it'll work nicely on both servers in both scenarions.

If it's hacked together without a solution package then you'll need to install it on all servers.

Comment: I agree, a webpart should be packaged into .wsp package and installed via stsadm, that way data is stored in the configuration database and should populate correctly if new servers are added to a farm.